# Firebase Analytics: combine paramaters/values in console-view

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, parameters, firebase-analytics

I'm new to Firebase (and stackoverflow) and have a question:

Is it possible in the console view for firebase to combine the data? What I want to achieve is that when in "parameter_name" I select for example the "scene_interaction" and automatically the "scene_name" displays only the values for the "scene_interaction"-parameter (and ignoring "button_pressed" and "main"). See screenshot for this:

[image: screenshot firebase]

The event is logged as follow:

```
parameterEntry = new Firebase.Analytics.Parameter[] 
{
    new Firebase.Analytics.Parameter("parameter_name", parameterList[i].parameterName),
    new Firebase.Analytics.Parameter("action_value", parameterList[i].value),
    new Firebase.Analytics.Parameter("action_type", parameterList[i].type),
    new Firebase.Analytics.Parameter("scene_name", parameterList[i].scene),
    new Firebase.Analytics.Parameter("scene_type", parameterList[i].scene_type)
    };
}

Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent(eventName, parameterEntry);
```

I hope someone can help me. Preferably without  the use of BigQuery.